# Automorphism implies identity?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, $\tau_1, \tau_2$ be two topologies on the set $X$. If there is a homeomorphism $f: (X, \tau_1)\rightarrow (X, \tau_2)$, then should $\tau_1=\tau_2$?

Comment: Not necessarily. The upper-limit topology on $\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to the lower-limit topology, for example.

Comment: What is the upper-limit topology and the lower-limit topology? Can you explain or give a reference?

Comment: No. For $X=\{1,2\}$, consider $\tau_1=\{ \,\emptyset, \{1\}, X\,\}$ and $\tau_2=\{\,\emptyset,\{2\},X\,\}$

Comment: @Lao-tzu: DavidMitra's example is simpler, but for future reference see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology).

Comment: True when $f$ is the identity.

Answer (score 1):

One can construct counterexamples following this recipe:

1. Choose a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and a bijection $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $f$ is not an open map for $\tau$.
2. Define a topology $\tau^\prime$ on $X$ declaring $S\in\tau^\prime$ if and only if $f^{-1}(S)\in\tau$.
3. Then $\tau\neq\tau^\prime$ but $f$ is a homeomorphism between $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau^\prime)$

Comment: Thank you! You give me the idea that an bijection define a new topology on the same set, and we just need to find such a map that map the original topology to a different one.